# Split text using any suggested method

Tags: sql, split, data-munging

I have a plain text like this:

```
Cart ID: A3N42M / Copy: A3N42P PO: 5000021337 Invoice: 3110021337
Cart ID: A3N3ZW / Copy: A3N3ZX/ PO: 5000021335 Invoice: 3110021335 
Cart ID: A3N3ZL / Copy: A3N3ZM PO: 5000021336 Invoice: 3110021336 
Original: A3N444 / Copy: A3N445 PO: 5000021340 Invoice: 3130021340
Original: A3N44C / Copy: A3N44D PO: 5000021341 Invoice: 3130021341
Original: A3N44G / Copy: A3N44H PO: 5000021342 Invoice: 3130021342
Cart ID: A3N3ZZ / Copy: A3N428 PO: A3N3ZZ01
Cart ID: A3N3ZQ / Copy: A3N3ZV PO: A3N3ZQ01
Cart ID: A3N336 / Copy: A3N337 PO: A3N33601
E3M49D / E3M49Q - PO: 4620028049
E3M49N / E3M49X
E3M49P / E3M49Y
```

And I need to split the cart IDs from that text, and end up in something like this:

```
A3N42M
A3N42P
A3N3ZW
...
E3M49N
...
```

These IDs are always 6-digit length, and always starts with `A`, `E` or `P` (`AXXXXX`, `EXXXXX`, `PXXXXX`, etc...).

Is there any way (using any script or any program language) that I can achieve this?

This plain text is currently on a spreadsheet table, and I need to separate these IDs to use in a SQL query for later, thanks!

Comment: Almost every language could perform this if it had too, what language do you know or would you prefer to work in?

Comment: If you use python look at [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

Comment: Actually I just have a very basic program language knowledge, little bit of Java ... but not enough to try to achieve this

Comment: You could also use a text editor with regex find and replace to perform splits.

Comment: what text editor do you use?

Comment: I use Notepad++, I saw some tips on the internet on how to do it bookmarking lines etc, but I still did not manage to make it work, but I'll use the python code below that a fellow posted, thanks a lot buddy :-)

Comment: When you say that the plain text is currently in a spreadsheet, do you mean that all of that text is in one cell? Or is it spanned across multiple cells.

Comment: Notepad++ has regex

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch It's all in the same cell ... I could do a simple `=SPLIT` and use space as delimiter, but it would also give me work in order to delete the cells that does not have the content I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regex Data-Munging

---

You can perform this via `regex` substitutions (or find and replace). I happened to do this in python, but you could use the same regex patterns (`'^[^/]*?: '`, `'/.*'`) in any language or text editor that supports them.

#### Regex Explanation

1. `'^[^/]*?: '` - start and beginning of string (first `^`), match multiple non-`\` characters in a non greedy way (`[^/]*?]`), a `:`, then a .
2. `'/.*'` - match all `/`, then multiple any character (`.`)

#### Processing Example (in Python)

```
import re

text = '''
Cart ID: A3N42M / Copy: A3N42P PO: 5000021337 Invoice: 3110021337
Cart ID: A3N3ZW / Copy: A3N3ZX/ PO: 5000021335 Invoice: 3110021335 
Cart ID: A3N3ZL / Copy: A3N3ZM PO: 5000021336 Invoice: 3110021336 
Original: A3N444 / Copy: A3N445 PO: 5000021340 Invoice: 3130021340
Original: A3N44C / Copy: A3N44D PO: 5000021341 Invoice: 3130021341
Original: A3N44G / Copy: A3N44H PO: 5000021342 Invoice: 3130021342
Cart ID: A3N3ZZ / Copy: A3N428 PO: A3N3ZZ01
Cart ID: A3N3ZQ / Copy: A3N3ZV PO: A3N3ZQ01
Cart ID: A3N336 / Copy: A3N337 PO: A3N33601
E3M49D / E3M49Q - PO: 4620028049
E3M49N / E3M49X
E3M49P / E3M49Y
'''

text = re.sub('^[^/]*?: ([]*?)', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
text = re.sub('/.*', '', text)

print text
```

---

```
A3N42M 
A3N3ZW 
A3N3ZL 
A3N444 
A3N44C 
A3N44G 
A3N3ZZ 
A3N3ZQ 
A3N336 
E3M49D 
E3M49N 
E3M49P
```

## EDIT

---

#### Updated Regex Explanation

Updated `regex` per author's request.

1. match any character (`.*?`) (non-greedy), followed by a capture group of (`(...)`) of a character class (`[AEP]`) followed by at least one character class (`[0-9]+`) followed by four word characters (`\w{4}`), followed by another capture group of any character (`(.*)`)
2. All of this is matched and replaced with the capture group variables with a newline in between (`\1\n\2`), essentially splitting rows where IDs occur twice
3. Repeat steps with only the first capture group to handle the newlines containing the second ID

#### Updated Processing

```
text = re.sub(r'.*?([AEP][0-9]+\w{4})(.*)', r'\1\n\2', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
text = re.sub(r'.*?([AEP][0-9]+\w{4}).*', r'\1', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print text
```

---

```
A3N42M
A3N42P
A3N3ZW
A3N3ZX
A3N3ZL
A3N3ZM
A3N444
A3N445
A3N44C
A3N44D
A3N44G
A3N44H
A3N3ZZ
A3N428
A3N3ZQ
A3N3ZV
A3N336
A3N337
E3M49D
E3M49Q
E3M49N
E3M49X
E3M49P
E3M49Y
```

Comment: Hello, I installed Python and tried to run the .py file using the command prompt, but I got this: `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`, am I doing anything wrong? Sorry never played with Python before, I just ran: `python file.py` in the command prompt.

Comment: If you have Python 3 use `print(text)`

Comment: Thanks! it almost did the trick, just some IDs missing after the `/` in the text, as you can see in this [Image](http://imgur.com/a/wSWLP)

Comment: Oh assumed you only wanted the first IDs. You will need to change your `regex` patterns to handle that. But now you have a recipe to start with. Have a look at [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) to play with developing useful patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did a little research and I could come up with a regex that found all my cart IDs in the list: `(a|e|p)[0-9]{1,}\w{4}` -- [IMAGE](http://imgur.com/a/WcImY) -- Now, is it possible in that python code to use this regex and delete everything that does not match it?

Comment: Remember to accept the answer and up vote if you approve, [we both get rep! (you get +2 reputation for accepting!)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/292533)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm, I accepted your post as the answer, I just cannot up vote due to my reputation, sorry for the delay! :-)